# Boost state machine deferred event

Tags: c++, boost, boost-msm

```
struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
  Row < waiting, update, pending, send_replace, none>,
  Row < pending, update, none, Defer, none>,
  Row < pending, replaced, waiting, ack_replace, none>
  > { };
```

If second transition is Defer twice in a row, is it possible to discard the first one?